# How can I avoid map size and scale changes in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.16

I set up a print composer for an area of my map.
I'm exporting it as a series of pdfs (with different layers turned on) and over-laying the pdfs in corel.
All of a sudden, my map window changed size and scale and I have no idea what I did.
I tried undo but it didn't alter the new window, just undid the various layer changes that I had made.

I tried quitting without saving, but it seems to have auto saved.
Can someone guess what may have happened and tell me how to avoid it happening again?
I'm unable to replicate the exact area now and even when I type in the same scale, it exports slightly differently than it did.

We are getting ready to switch across to Qgis and this sort of exporting is something I do easily and reliably with our very old mini GIS. I do this regularly and need to know how to avoid this issue in the future.

---

I was using QGIS 2.16.1, I inserted a map window into print composer and set the scale and was exporting images from it. The map window suddenly changed size and scale, with no clear cause, and I could find no way to set it back.

What can make the map window change size and scale? Perhaps a key combination that I may have pressed while I was editing the layers in the main window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid changing the scale and/or position of the map, you can lock the map item in the items panel of print compose. This will avoid making any accidental changes.

Closing QGIS, without saving the project, should also have enabled you to get back to the previous configuration.

Comment: I'll look for a lock setting when I next use it. I did try saving without closing but that did not work.